# Metro UI style close/minimize/maximize buttons

Tags: qt4, styles, microsoft-metro

how can I style the maximize/minimize/close buttons of an application to match the Metro UI version? I would do something like the one at right top corner: I'm using Qt 4.8 on Windows 7

[image]

Comment: You should create your own window frames. Qt uses system window frames. You can't style them

Comment: can you please explain better what are window frames and where can I find docs about Qt to create them?

Comment: Window frame is this thin border around your widget, that contains tittle bar and close/minimize/maximize buttons. To achieve what you want you will have to create frameless window with widgets that replace them

Comment: Seems like you pretty much answered Stefano's question. You should put this in the answer box. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to style window frame as it is managed by underlying OS. You need create frameless window and add widgets responsible for minimizing/closing/maximizin